# Apple site on Safari not working properly

Tags: websites

Here is an interesting issue: on the [Mac](http://www.apple.com/mac/) and [iPod](http://www.apple.com/ipod/) sections of Apple's site there are the products subsections (Mac, Applications, Accessories, Server, on the Mac page and Products, iTunes and more, on the iPod page). Now, when you click on, say, the Applications link, the images above should slide out and be replaced with the images of Apple's apps. Except from Safari on my machine it doesn't.
Also, the Web Inspector shows two JavaScript errors that. This happens only in Safari.
Any body else observed this?
Any idea why?

Mac OS X 10.6.8
MacBook Pro 8,2
Safari 5.0.2

[image]

Comment: This works for me - either they fixed the errors server side or your safari isn't default. Have you disabled any extensions or plugiins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out. [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) was blocking an Omniture tracking script: http://images.apple.com/metrics/scripts/s_code_h.js

Thanks for the tip, bmike.